# How to create subcolumns under a main column

Tags: pandas

I want to create a common column departments under which there should be subcolumns like R&D,Spend,Administration,Marketing.

```
   R&D Spend    Administration  Marketing Spend State   Profit
   165349.20    136897.80      471784.10    New York    192261.83
```

I tried to use multiplex but got stuck here!

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['R&D Spend','Administration','Marketing'], ['Department']])
```

Thanks in advance!!

Expected output:

```
               Department                
*************************************** 
R&D Spend   Administration  Marketing   Spend State  Profit 
 165349.20   136897.80     471784.10    New York    192261.83
```

Comment: What do you want for the other columns? A MultiIndex will be for the entire DataFrame, so 'Spend State' and 'Profit' need *something* for that outer level. Alternatively, you could move them to the Index

Comment: in addition to @ALollz your multiindex in the wrong order `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Department'],['R&D Spend','Administration','Marketing']])` you need to define all the columnsyour otherwise you'll get a length mismatch / `ValueError`

Comment: @Alollz - I want to categorize only the mentioned columns and other columns like profit ,spend state should be default.